# FBWebDIalogs generates 'An error has occured' when trying to post a feed in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, dialog, feed

I'd already implemented an App both on FB and iOS that published updates to the users timeline using the Feed Dialog.  This was working as intended up until a few months ago, when most users started seeing the 'An Error has Occurred. Please try again later' page.

I set out to update the FB SDK to the latest version and hopefully fix this issue.  Initially I have had success posting stories with the basic tutorial app, but once I removed the native IOS FB login settings, the error screen re-appeared.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start with a fresh iOS simulator.
2. Log in to Facebook via the setting screen.
3. Run the basic tutorial, with FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:parameters:handler: added as a share button.
4. Login works as expected.
5. Share works as expected and presents the web dialog allowing me to post to my timeline.
6. Quit the App (not just switch out of it)
7. From Settings, delete the Facebook account.
8. Re-run the App and tap login -- you will be presented with the web login dialog.
9. Login and 'share' to make the call to FBWebDialogs.
10. Note the 'error has occurred' screen.
11. Dismiss this and tap the logout button.
12. Tap login, and once again, you will be presented with the web login dialog.
13. Login and notice you are asked to confirm the FBApps access (you'll be told it's already been authorized).  Tap OK.
14. Tap Share and you will now see the 'Feed' dialog as expected.
15. (You can logout or not at this step, it makes no difference). Go back to the iOS settings page and re-add your Facebook account.
16. Run the App, and tap log in.
17. You will be presented with the web UI login screen (this is not expected).
18. After logging in, tap share to initiate a FBWebDialog call.
19. Note the 'error has occured' screen.  At this point, it is impossible to post except by deleting the Facebook account in iOS settings and going back to step 8.

The problem seems to occur if the user ever deletes their FB settings from the device.  Also, if the user has had FB settings on their device via the iOS settings screen and then tries to log in via the web ui, the feed dialog post will fail.

I'd like to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/16169133/ios-sharing-an-error-has-occurred-please-try-again-later

Comment: I disagree -- while similar to the linked bug, it's not the same -- unless you know something I dont.  I dont delete the App or the App permissions, just log into FB either through the web interface or the built-in iOS method.

Comment: The key similarity is in both cases you're presented with the web login dialog and after that you get an error.